# According to the RCC, why did God create so many planets?

Tags: catholicism, creation

Why did God create so many planets? The argument that He had to in order to make the universe work is just opinion based because He could or can change all laws of nature and the universe and create  them whatever way He wants.
But According to the RCC, why is there so many planets?

Comment: The question seems quite clear and, by limiting it to RCC doctrine, is not too broad. The problem is that the RCC probably does not have a doctrine on this. You can't have a specific teaching on everything, and you could even say the exoplanets may have caught the Church by surprise.

Comment: Are you asking: "Why is there inequality/diversity in creation?" Viz., "Why isn't the universe a monotonous being but full of so many different types of beings?"  St. Thomas discusses this in [_Summa Theologica_ I q. 47 a. 1 "Of the Distinction of Things in General"](http://dhspriory.org/thomas/summa/FP/FP047.html#FPQ47OUTP1).

Comment: @DickHarfield The question seems too specific.

Comment: @Geremia  This is my feeling.  At the time I wrote my comment, I was commenting on the votes to close; I think a 'too broad' vote seems to have no been retracted.   But I think you and I probably agree that the question is unanswerable.  It's good to give reasons if this can help new contributors refine their questions.

Comment: @DickHarfield I agree and disagree.This is a large question and one should have an answer to this question.I would guess The RCC has one.The question is certainley not unanswerable,I would guess there is an answer in judaism.

Comment: @Geremia That is some deep stuff."Secondly, because matter is for the sake of the form, and not the form for the matter, and the distinction of things comes from their proper forms. Therefore the distinction of things is not on account of the matter; but rather, on the contrary, created matter is formless, in order that it may be accommodated to different forms."St. Thomas

Comment: Aigle, given the RCC's belief (and for that matter, a general Christian belief) that God created all of creation (which includes the whole universe itself), what's a few planets here and there?  -1 for lack of research before asking this question.

Comment: @SimplyaChristian Actually I agree with you.  I did not DV nor vote to close this Q.  If anything, I was commenting on  votes that it was  'unclear' and 'too broad' (since retracted).  I felt the Q should stand and that anyone who wished should answer it (as Caleb has now done).

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge and research, the RCC does not express a position on this issue. Like many other mysteries of the physical universe this subject is not specified mentioned in Scripture nor does it have any bearing on faith in so far as knowledge about God would affect how we live in relation to him. While the RCC does have doctrines about lots of scientific details¹ like this for one reason or another, even they haven't felt the need to explain this².

<sub>¹ In fact they have frequently erred on the side of being too explicit about matters not pertaining to faith and not specified in Scripture only to be later contradicted by scientific developments. If any mainline branch of Christianity was going to have a doctrine about this it would be the RCC.</sub>

<sub>² Or perhaps even if it had come up, they recognized the lack of sources on the matter.</sub>